# What is the name of that widget

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget, android-appwidget

Can you please tell me the name of that widget shown in the image below " on the right"? I want to learn how to use it and find some tutorial for it but i do not know how it is called

[image]

Comment: Looks like a [pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_menu)/[radial menu](http://beaucollins.github.io/radial-menu/). Take a look at something like [ArcMenu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu) and [CircularFloatingActionMenu](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu) which are implementations of the menu using a custom view.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a [circle menu](https://www.google.de/search?q=circle+menu+android&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=968&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIhsWbrqitxwIVQbUaCh3kyA1f)